line break makes second line go outside of circle
 .circle1{
        height: 150px;
        width: 150px;
        background-color: #BC903F;
        border-radius: 50%;
        margin-right: 15px;
        line-height: 150px;
    }
    
    
    .circle1:hover{
        border: #8D1D22 solid 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
       
    }
   
    
    .speech_bubble{
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .speech_bubble>p{
        font-size: 15px;
    }
    .in_circle{
        height:150px;
        width:150px;
        font-size: 36px;
        text-align: center;
        .month{
            color: #8D1D22;
        }
        .day{
            color: aliceblue;
        }
    }
}

this is the css of the circle That I want to have my text in, it should be the month at the top and the day at the bottom.
html:

               <div class="speech_bubble">
                   <span class="circle1">
                       <div class="in_circle">
                           <strong><span class="month">Oct</span></strong>
                           <strong><span class="day">29</span></strong>
                       </div>
                   </span>                      
              </div>

I want to ask how to center the text in the circle to something like this:
enter image description here, I can put the month and day side by side centered inside the circle, but when I add a line break between the two p elements it sends it too far down, making the day text go out of the circle, I also tried making them both a <p> but the same problem occurs
any suggestion is welcomed and wanted.

Remove line-height: 150px; then follow the duplicate.
